# Delete object (single image) in Amazon S3 using php Yii2 not working?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, yii2

Here I have the code of connection

```
 $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
           'key'    => 'xxxxxxxxx',
           'secret' => '0xxxxxxxxxx',
           'version' => 'latest',
           'region' => 'us-west-2',
     ))
```

Here the bucket name   `$bucket = 'ariana-ios-storages';` and here the name of file `$p =  parse_url($images->name)` which is the
name of file in amazon to delete;

Here is the code to delete the file

```
$delete =  $s3->deleteObject([
               'Bucket' => $bucket,
               'Key'    => $p['path']
            ]);
        var_dump($delete);
        exit();
```

The file path is generated like [this](https://ariana-ios-storages.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads%5Cba%5C40%5C0a3fdc74.png);

It is not deleting the single file from the bucket so can any one help what i am missing

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam

Comment: Read your bucket logs and see what file this code is *trying* to delete.  The problem should become apparent.  Deletions always succeed on S3 because `DELETE x` means "remove the file named x if it exists."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  public function actionDeleteImages($id)
  {
    $exportImage=  \common\models\ExportImages::findOne($id);
    $base_url='base url to bucket';
    $s3 = S3Client::factory(array(
        'key'    => 'xxxxxxx',
        'secret' => '0pdfOx21xxxxxxxxxx',
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region' => 'us-west-2',
    ));
    $bucket = 'name of bucket';
    $key=urldecode(explode($base_url,$exportImage->name)[1]);// $images->name is  Path from Db, base url is path to s3 server
    $delete =  $s3->deleteObject([
        'Bucket' => 'ariana-ios-storages',
        'Key' => $key
    ]);
    $object_exist =  $s3->doesObjectExist($bucket,$key);
    if(!$object_exist){
        return "succesfully deleted";
    }else{
        return "there is some problem while procesing the deletion";
    }
  }

}
```